# Xcode does not jump to objective c++ objects when I click on them

Tags: iphone, xcode, objective-c++

My Xcode project has a lot of Objective-C classes and also a lot of Objective C++ classes.  The latter have .mm files for their implementations.

When you command click on something in Xcode, Xcode is supposed to jump to the definition of whatever you clicked on.  For me, this only happens some of the time.

- If I am editing Objective C code and I command-click on an objective C object, it almost always works.
- If I am editing Objective C++ code and I command-click on an objective C object, it may or may not work.
- If I command-click on an objective-C++ object (anything with a .mm implementation), it almost never works, no matter what I am currently editing.

Does anyone know of a way to improve this?

Comment: What Xcode version are you using ?, maybe you could submit a report to Apple's Radar? ( https://bugreport.apple.com/ )

Comment: 4.0.2.  Submitting is a good idea.